# What Jersey dependency to add to avoid NoClassDefFoundError for jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Maps

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to run a a test that extends `JerseyTest` but when running it I'm getting a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/Maps
```

Any idea what dependency I'm missing? I've included the following jersey artifacts in my `pom.xml` and jersey.version is 2.5.1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'll need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

From http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/21/jersey-2-6-has-been-released-new-and-noteworthy/

> Jersey, from versions 2.6 for JAX-RS 2.0 and 1.18.1 for JAX-RS 1.1, no longer transitively brings Guava and ASM libraries to your application. This means that even when we still use them internally you can use different versions of these libraries. Classes from both of these libraries has been repackaged, `jersey.repackaged.com.google.common` and `jersey.repackaged.objectweb.asm` respectively, and shrinked to lower the footprint. ASM 5 is now part of jersey-server core module and for Guava we’ve created a separate bundle module [jersey-guava](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.6/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava) as this dependency is widely used in multiple Jersey modules.

You're using the Jersey **2.6** `jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2`.