# Get list of object instances of a rest client invocation in java ee 7

Tags: rest, java-ee-7

I use `java ee 7` on `Glassfish 4.1.1`. There is a rest service written in `C#` and it returns a collection of Book instances.
The code on the rest client side which send get request:

```
public List<Bandwcorpus> downloadBandWCorpus(String corpus) {
    Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    List<Bandwcorpus> ebooks=restClient
        .target("http://bookandwalk.pl/api/admindocumentlist")
        .queryParam("password", "XXXX").queryParam("corpusid", "YYYY")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(new GenericType<List<Book>>() {});
    restClient.close();
    return ebooks;
}
```

The Book class is a POJO:

```
public class Book {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer documentid;

    private String corpusid;

    private String corpusoriginalid;

    private float nett;

    private String currencyid;

    private int vat;

    private Discount discount;

    private Upoluj isbn;

    public Bandwcorpus() {

    }
}
```

My applied get function is based on http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_returning_a_list blog post and this solution was applied also in Java ee 7 tutorial.

Unfortunately, I get the following compile error in this case:

```
error: no suitable method found for get(<anonymous com.fasterxml.classmate.GenericType<List<Book>>>)
    List<Book> ebooks=restClient.target("http://bookandwalk.pl/api/admindocumentlist").queryParam("password", "XXXXX").queryParam("corpusid", "YYYYY").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<Book>>() {});
method SyncInvoker.<T#1>get(Class<T#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
    (argument mismatch; <anonymous com.fasterxml.classmate.GenericType<List<Bandwcorpus>>> cannot be converted to Class<T#1>))
method SyncInvoker.<T#2>get(javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
    (argument mismatch; <anonymous com.fasterxml.classmate.GenericType<List<Book>>> cannot be converted to javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T#2>))
```

where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:

- T#1 extends Object declared in method `<T#1>get(Class<T#1>)`
- T#2 extends Object declared in method
  `<T#2>get(javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T#2>)`

Any idea what do I make wrong if this is the suggested way by Oracle and other experts?

Comment: Could you post your structure for Bandwcorpus

Comment: @Ironluca, It was a typo. Everywhere you see Bandwcorpus it is the Book class I just copied it from the earlier version.

Comment: Try this and check, ArrayList<Book> obj=new ArrayList<>(); List<Bandwcorpus> ebooks=restClient.target("http://bookandwalk.pl/api/admindocumentlist").queryParam("password", "XXXX").queryParam("corpusid", YYYY").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(obj.getClass());

Comment: After checking your code I got the following runtime error: javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json;charset=utf-8, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: Check if Jackson provider is configured corretly, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442440/messagebodyreader-not-found-for-media-type-application-json

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found the solution:

```
List<Book> e=restClient
    .target("http://bookandwalk.pl/api/admindocumentlist")
    .queryParam("password", "XXXXXX")
    .queryParam("corpusid_or_languagecode", "Example")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get(new GenericType<List<Book>> () {});
```

Comment: The only annotation that could be useful, is that in the web service is not necessary to return a GeneryType<List<Book>> when you use @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) annotation, in this case, the conversion is implicit. Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

it worked like this for me, enjoy.

```java
public List<Persona> Buscar(String estado, String namescore) {

    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (estado != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("estado", estado);
    }
    if (namescore != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("namescore", namescore);
    }

    List<Persona> Personass= resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<Persona>>() {});
    return Personass;
}
```