# Server Tomcat v8.5 failed to start for hello world Jersey Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am setting up my Jersey Web Service but cant get it to run, Apache Tomcat 8.5 is error'ing out. See details below for simple code, my libs and error.

I created a Dynamic Web Project...
I added my Jersey files... (**am i missing any?**)

- javax.ws.rs-api.2.0.1.jar
- jersey-client.jar
- jersey-common.jar
- jersey-contaner-servlet.jar
- jersey-container-servlet.jar
- jersey-media-jaxb.jar
- jersey-server.jar

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <!-- The package where your resource classes are -->
        <param-value>WS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testApi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Java class

```
package ws;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

    @Path("test")
    public class Connect {
        @GET
        @Path("test")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String hello(){
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

My error before the pop-up saying failed to start Apachev8.5

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ThisApi]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ThisApi]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.<clinit>(ServiceFinder.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory.getAllServletContainerProviders(ServletContainerProviderFactory.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Function
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: See if this helps...this is for tomcat 7. Answer has listed all dependencies,     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754372/jersey-2-7-issue-while-running-it-on-apache-tomcat-7-0

Comment: I think so....ridiculous how may libs i needed, not sure which caused the difference but i'll hae to check that out another time....any idea what my test url is going to be?

Comment: localhost:port/your apps contextroot/test

Comment: hmmmm no doesnt seem to work.. I have /test/test from the java code...i have localhost:8081/ (thats ok) and my localroot - how do i determine if this is right? I also see paramValue in xml...so that gives me localhost:8081\contextroot\WS\test\test

Comment: Should be: localhost:8081/test/test

Comment: hmmm im getting 404 errors even at localhost... tomcat config issue perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `jersey-guava.jar`, which should contain the package-rebundled versions of the Google Guava classes, including `Function`. Jersey repackages the exact version they need so that you can still use the version of Guava you prefer from its original package structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22069399/27905 .

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava

Comment: Hey man, i added it as part of a fix to get tomcat running but...now i get http status 404 error

Comment: still having this error. tomcat manually started i can hit the localhost....i start my web service i cant hit local host

Comment: @Fearghal You should open a new question for that, including details of how you're deploying and launching Tomcat and your web app within it.

Comment: I did including my libs, my code, my tomcat version, some troubleshooting i did....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211334/tomcat-gives-http404-error-when-used-to-test-jersey-java-web-service