# tomcat gives http404 error when used to test jersey java web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a jersey java dynamic web project...a web service which i think is laid out correctly (hoping im wrong though). This web service runs off tomcat8.5 server on my win 10 laptop.

When Tomcat is manually started in services I can hit its home page at localhost:8081.

When i run my web service in eclipse i am denied with http 404 error 'request resource isnt available'. I cant even hit the localhost:8081 the same way i can when i start it manually and i cant see it started in 'services'...but eclipse says it is started. I see lots of red info warnings on startup but cant see any issue.

Help please!

Heres my setup:

Libs
[image]

Build Path
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>MyApi</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>service</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Java class

```
package ws;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("test")
public class Connect {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

My error
[image]

Comment: What resource is being requested in "When i run my web service in eclipse i am denied with http 404 error 'request resource isnt available'"?

Comment: i try to hit my web service url at localhost:8081\myApi\test\test...http404 so i try to hit localhost:8081 as i know that should be there...http404 again

Comment: You meant those to be forward slashes instead of backslashes, right? " 
i try to hit my web service url" means you, literally, or the "Run on Server" action? What does the **Servers View** show for the deployment of the project?

Comment: sorry yes meant '/'...me literally and run on server action. 'Severs' folder below he project has tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config. sould i check that config for anything?

Comment: Show it. Your project should be listed there as deploying to '/myApi' if this is supposed to work as you expect.

Comment: hmmm i dnt think it is, although im not 100% sure what you mean. Thx for he help btw...i'll put a screenshot of my server and error in question, let me know if this tells you any more.

Comment: Update....if i rightclick on my project under the tomcat server in servers tab in eclipse...and select debug with chromium...i get this....Unable to detect 'webapp' folder in the project for debugging
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to detect 'webapp' folder in the project for debugging....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135624/discussion-between-nitind-and-fearghal).

Comment: An obvious one (you probably just mistyped when pasting/adjusting the sample) - in web.xml you configure the Jersey package scanning with a package named "service", whereas your resource is in the "ws" package.